# Dalvik bytecode and compare to 0 jumps

Tags: bytecode, dalvik, dex

In dalvik, there is no `ifnull` or `ifnonnull` like in java bytecode. There is only `if-eqz` and `if-nez`. They can be used to compare int values to `(int) 0`, or object values to `(Object) null`. Is it also possible to compare objects with `(Object) null` using `if-ltz`, `if-lez` or similar, or is this illegal? What about comparison instructions like `if-gt`, can they compare an `int` with an `Object`?

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with Dalvik, but I believe the answer is no. The constant 0 is special cased in the type checker. You can't compare arbitrary objects and integers.